# React function is showing that object is empty when I try to write it out to the console

Tags: reactjs

I am using this constant function whenever an element in a sortable list is moved:

```
const arrayMoveMutate = (array, from, to) => {
    array.splice(
        to < 0 ? array.length + to : to,
        0,
        array.splice(from, 1)[0]
    );
};

const arrayMove = (array, from, to) => {
    array = array.slice();
    arrayMoveMutate(array, from, to);
    return array;
};

 const onSortEnd = React.useCallback(
        ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
            setPlayer(player =>
                arrayMove(player, oldIndex, newIndex)
            );
            console.log('mock api POST to save new index positions: ', player);
            console.log('oldIndex: ', oldIndex);
            console.log('newIndex: ', newIndex);
        },
        []
    );
```

Here is the SortableList:

```
<SortableList player={player} onSortEnd={onSortEnd} />
```

Every time a move an element, I do see the oldIndex and newIndex in my console change.

However, 'player' is always empty.

How would I pass the 'player' object to onSortEnd so that I can do my api POST?

thanks!

Comment: Are you able to hit a debugger in `arrayMove`?  Adding the code for that function would also help.

Comment: Can you add `arrayMove` implementation ?

Comment: @MattCroak thanks, I added those function!

Comment: @Easwar I added two new functions.  thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need but if its the player, simply `onSortEnd={(props) => onSortEnd(props, player)}` should do it ?

Comment: Both player and the moved player are available in the setPlayer callback: `setPlayer(player => {
  const newPlayer = arrayMove(player, oldIndex, newIndex);
  console.log(newPlayer, player);
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`player` in the `console.log` statement is a reference to the hook value created in your `useState` hook. Hence add it to the callbacks deps as below to get the fresh value, else it will always be empty within the callback :

```
const onSortEnd = React.useCallback(({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
  setPlayer(player => arrayMove(player, oldIndex, newIndex));
  console.log("mock api POST to save new index positions: ", player);
  console.log("oldIndex: ", oldIndex);
  console.log("newIndex: ", newIndex);
}, [player]);
```

That said, this deps is only required for logging the value inside the callback. As you are passing function to `setPlayer`, it will always take the latest value of the state irrespective of the deps. Hence the state should be setting fine even with your code. If still facing issues, try setting the deps and try again.

Comment: The second parameter of `React.useCallback` is the deps or dependencies in short. I had set `player` variable as a dependency so that the callback is re-created if `player` changes. Please refer the docs here : `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback`

Comment: @Easwar The deps is not needed because setPlayer gets the player, code needs to be moved in the callback to setPlayer.

Comment: @HMR : Yes, I had mentioned that in the bottom paragraph. The sole purpose of putting `player` in deps was so that the first `console.log` statement gets the fresh value. Apart from that I do not see any reason for deps.